# Appending title void transition animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add transition() and append("title") to allow animation and hover over tooltip at the same time on my scatterplot. But when I add transition, tooltip no longer pops out.

```
 const circles = g.merge(gEnter).selectAll('circle').data(data);
  
  circles
    .enter().append('circle').merge(circles).transition().duration(2000)
      .attr('cy', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
      .attr('cx', d => xScale(xValue(d)))
      .attr('r', d => (d.Score*1.29)+1)
      .attr("fill", d=>colorArray(d.Type))
      .append("title").text(d => (d.Country_or_region+ "\n" +"Rank: "+ d.Overall_rank))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything after `.transition()` is a *transition*, and there is no `.append()` method for a transition. If you inspect the console you'll probably see an error.

That said, if for whatever reason you want append the `title` only after the transition started, you can use the `.on("start")` method:

```
.on("start", function() {
    d3.select(this).append("title").text("foo")
})
```

Here is the demo, there is no title at the beginning. After the transition starts you'll get the title when hovering over the circle:

```js
const circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.transition()
  .duration(20000)
  .delay(2000)
  .attr("cx", 100)
  .on("start", function() {
    d3.select(this).append("title").text("foo")
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle r="20" cx="20" cy="100"></circle>
</svg>
```